# magento: moving cart in another block

Tags: magento

I'm a Magento newbie, and I'm trying to separate my cart link from the other links in the navigation bar.

I did these steps:
1)Configured a new module under `etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Marco_TopRightLinks>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Marco_TopRightLinks>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2)added in `app/code/local/Marco/TopRightLinks/Block`
the `Links.php` file, with these contents:

```
class Marco_TopRightLinks_Block_Links extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Links
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('page/template/logged-links.phtml');
    }
}
```

3)added in `app/code/local/Marco/TopRightLinks/etc`
the `config.xml` file, with these contents:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Marco_TopRightLinks>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Marco_TopRightLinks>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <topright>
                <class>Marco_TopRightLinks_Block</class>
            </topright>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

4)Changed `page.xml` from this:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
  <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

to this:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
  <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
  <block type="topright/links" name="top.right_links" as="topRightLinks"/>
```

5) changed `checkout.xml` from this:

to this:

```
<!-- Mage_Checkout -->
<reference name="top.right_links">
  <block type="topright/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
    <action method="addCartLink"></action>
    <!--<action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>-->
  </block>
</reference>
```

added under `[my_template]/page/template`
the `right-links.phtml` file

This results in a Magento exception:

```
Invalid method Marco_TopRightLinks_Block_Links::removeLinkByUrl(Array
(
  [0] => http://mysitecom/checkout/cart/
)
```

Can you help me in understanding what's happening and what i could do? (i don't want to touch any innter magento methods, I'm sure the `addCartLink` works very well as it is :D)  my goal is simply to move the cart link in another place into my html

EDIT:
if, instead of extending `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links`

```
class Marco_TopRightLinks_Block_Links extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Links
```

I extend `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`

```
class Marco_TopRightLinks_Block_Links extends Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links
```

the exception changes in

```
Invalid method Marco_TopRightLinks_Block_Links::addCartLink
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing topright to toprightlinks in the cinnfig .xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Marco_TopRightLinks>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Marco_TopRightLinks>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <toprightlinks>
                <class>Marco_TopRightLinks_Block</class>
            </toprightlinks>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: In this case, it does not recognize my created block

Answer (score 0):

here i am giving you idea to change template from one to another with your custom block also

you can add your block via the layout system (which is how the normal content is added as well)?

Define a layout XML file for your module if you haven't already:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module module="Your_Module">
                <file>your/module.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Use your layout file (app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/your/module.xml) to add a block to the and layout update handles. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <a_handle_for_you>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text" name="yourblock">
                <action method="setText">
                    <arg>You should see this text.</arg>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </a_handle_for_you>
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <update handle="a_handle_for_you" />
    </checkout_onepage_success>
    <checkout_multishipping_success>
        <update handle="a_handle_for_you" />
    </checkout_multishipping_success>
</layout>
```

you can also refer [Magento Knowledge Base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates). to get deep idea to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The error was that in `checkout.xml` I shouldn't replace the block type. Magento should use its own. I should only change the block type in `page.xml`, so the container is changing, while the content is remaining the same